# Jack not loading all the settings at startup

Tags: sound, scripts, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I can´t make my system recall the whole audio configuration at startup.

After playing a lot with Jack, Carla and scripts, I've found this way to make my system (manually) work:
[Here is a little video of my turnaround](https://www.loom.com/share/d0d5ed3b6cb94078bffaaaf8440aef9b?sid=69a13ba0-2e06-465b-acc4-41c33325c0f9)

My sequence:

1. Start Jack
2. Start script:

```
pacmd set-default-sink jack_out
pacmd set-default-source jack_in
sleep 2
pactl load-module module-jack-sink client_name=pulse_out2 channels=2 connect=no
pactl load-module module-jack-source client_name=pulse_in2 channels=2 connect=no
pactl load-module module-jack-sink client_name=pulse_out3 channels=2 connect=no
pactl load-module module-jack-source client_name=pulse_in3 channels=2 connect=no

sleep 2
### alsa_in -j U1-Input -d hw:CARD=U192k -r 48000 >/dev/null &
#alsa_in -j USB-Mic -d hw:CARD=Device -r 48000 -c 1 >/dev/null &
alsa_in -j 4x4 -d hw:CARD=US4x4HR -r 48000 -c 4 >/dev/null &
alsa_out -j Envy -d hw:CARD=sofhdadsp -r 48000 >/dev/null &
alsa_out -j U2-Out -d hw:CARD=U192k -r 48000 >/dev/null &
alsa_out -j U-Aurics -d hw:CARD=CODEC -r 48000 >/dev/null &

carla -n carla-jtm-estudio.carxp &
```

3. Open Graphic on QjackCtl
4. Connect manually the system output to the card (U2-Out)

I have three cards: 1 for headphones, 1 for monitors and 1 for recording 4 channels

My system is running Ubuntu (Studio) 22.04.3 LTS

My question is:

**How can I finally automate this on startup?**

I've already tried putting the script on QjackCtl and saving the session after the manual connection with no success.

Thanks for any hints! ***Javier***